# Java: Creating a String of length X with random chars

Tags: java, tostring

The Problem I have to do is as follows

> public static String randomDNAString(int dnaLength)
>   /**  * @param dnaLength a non-negative int  * @return a random String
>   of length dnaLength comprised of the four chars A, T, G, and C  */

I thought I did it correctly (though incredibly inefficiently) but it doesn't return anything.  Here's my code.  Any help is appreciated.

```
    public static String randomDNAString(int dnaLength){
    Random rand = new Random();
    char[] dna;
    dna = new char[dnaLength];
    for(int i = 0; i<dnaLength;i++){
        int tempC = rand.nextInt(4);
        if(tempC == 0)
            dna[i] = 'A';
        if(tempC == 1)
            dna[i] = 'G';
        if(tempC == 2)
            dna[i] = 'C';
        if(tempC == 3)
            dna[i] = 'T';

    }
    return (java.util.Arrays.toString(dna));
}
```

Comment: What does it return? This seems to be fine.

Comment: It's supposed to return a String.  But when I run it, nothing gets returned

Comment: @Jonerhan I ran it. It works. `[A, G, G, G, A, G, G, C, A, A]`

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not getting an error, but the console doesn't return anything either

Comment: Why do you expect the console to show anything? None of your code that you've shown here has a `print()` call. Where is your `main()` method? What does it do?

Comment: Got it:  I was looking at this for 40 mins and just now realized I called this in the main, but didn't put it in a println statement.  I'm dumb.  thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

The other answer's suggestion using of using [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) was a good one. However, you can make this even simpler:

```
public static String randomDNAString(int dnaLength) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    StringBuilder dna = new StringBuilder(dnaLength);

    for (int i = 0; i < dnaLength; i++) {
        dna.append("ACGT".charAt(rand.nextInt(4)));
    }

    return dna.toString();
}
```

Comment: Nice one! This is a lot smarter than my derpy switch statement :)

Answer (score 0):

We can improve on your answer by changing the if chain to a `switch` statement and using a `StringBuilder`.

```
public static String randomDNAString(int dnaLength) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    StringBuilder dna = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<dnaLength;i++) {
        switch(rand.nextInt(4)) {
            case 0:
                dna.append("A");
                break;
            case 1:
                dna.append("C");
                break;
            case 2:
                dna.append("G");
                break;
            case 3:
                dna.append("T");
                break;
        }
    }
    return dna.toString();
}
```

To print the output, try:

```
System.out.println(randomDNAString(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with this.  I'm just dumb and when I called it in the main I used

```
randomDNAString(20);
```

instead of

```
System.out.println(randomDNAString(20));
```

Thanks for your help everyone, I'm just dumb sometimes